# redirecting a user to home page after login from facebook Auth provider

Tags: visualforce, authentication, federated-authentication

I saw this tutorial on fb Auth provider, and I successfully implemented it.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sso_provider_facebook.htm&language=en_US#sso_provider_facebook

After authorization it redirects to /`services/authcallback/00D90000000oX2GEAU/FacebookProvider1`.  I want it to redirect to another Visualforce page.  Is it possible??

Comment: how to use auth provider with connected app??please explain!!

Comment: no i didn't try anything.when i authorized my app with facebook it will goto authcallback url and give an xml.i want to override this xml page.please help.how to override it or redirect to another page .i am clueless.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `site` parameter to your SSO URL.

> https://login.salesforce.com/services/auth/sso/org/suffix?site=https%3A%2F%2Fmy.force.com%2F

Reference - [Using the Site Parameter](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sso_provider_addl_params_site.htm&language=en_US#sso_provider_addl_params_site.xml)